# Custom queryset with 2 ForeignKeys to the same Object

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model that have 2 ForeignKeys to the same Model:

```
    class Note(models.Model):
        sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='sender_note', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                      related_name='reciever_note', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  status = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
 action = models.CharField(choices=NOTE_CHOICES, max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

There are situation, when the reciever an the sender are the same user, but in the majority of cases are different users.

I created a custom queryset, where I use a RawQueryset:

```
   qs_str = 'SELECT N.id, N.status,N.action, U.email AS email FROM notes_note AS N LEFT JOIN users_user AS U on N.sender_id=U.id WHERE action IN %s AND status IS NOT TRUE AND U.is_staff=%s'

     qs = Note.objects.raw(qs_str, [action, user_is_staff])
```

I need to get:

1. both receiver and sender (to get attributes from them especially email)
2. check if sender is staff or not

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a raw query for such a simple case..

```
Note.objects.filter(sender__is_staff = True, action__in = action)
```

if you really want to optimize to prefetch sender/receiver you can use `select_related('sender', 'receiver')`.

Comment: If prefetch is used there are 2 queries not one, but this is not the issue. I want to get the info(email) for both recipient and sender at the same time, raw or not raw.

Comment: @user3541631 so where is the problem? just access it with note.sender.email and note.receiver.email?

Comment: note.sender.email and note.receiver.email generates 2 new queries, so will be 3, what I'm trying to do, is get everything in one join query.

Comment: have you tried `Note.objects.filter(sender__is_staff = True, action__in = action).select_related('sender', 'receiver')` ? imho it should only generate one query and join sender, receiver